# Scala converts map to Tuple implicitly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a array of map based on few condition. Following is my function.  Even though I am provided `Map` scala force me to have a `tuple` as return type. Is there a way I can fix it?

```
 def getSchemaMap(schema: StructType): Array[(String, String)] ={
    schema.fields.flatMap {
      case StructField(name, StringType, _, _) => Map(name-> "String")
      case StructField(name, IntegerType, _, _) => Map(name-> "int")
      case StructField(name, LongType, _, _) => Map(name-> "int")
      case StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _) => Map(name-> "int")
      case StructField(name, TimestampType, _, _) => Map(name-> "timestamp")
      case StructField(name, DateType, _, _) => Map(name-> "date")
      case StructField(name, BooleanType, _, _) => Map(name-> "boolean")
      case StructField(name, _:DecimalType, _, _) => Map(name-> "decimal")
      case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Map(name-> "String")

    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you want a map with a single element? Surely you can just do `(name -> "String")` instead of `Map(name -> "String")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to extract the columns (pairs of name/type) into a dictionary of `Map[String, String]`. You can use the build-in functionality for this and leverage the existing API hence I don't see the need for any custom pattern matching.

You can use `df.schema.fields` or `df.schema.toDDL` as explained next:

```scala
df.schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.dataType.typeName)).toMap // also try out f.dataType.simpleString
// res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col1 -> string, col2 -> integer, col3 -> string, col4 -> string)

df.schema.toDDL.split(",").map{f => (f.split(" ")(0), f.split(" ")(1))}.toMap
// res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(`col1` -> STRING, `col2` -> INT, `col3` -> STRING, `col4` -> STRING)
```

And with function:

```scala
def schemaToMap(schema: StructType): Map[String, String] =
    schema.fields.map(f => (f.name, f.dataType.typeName)).toMap
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `toMap` to convert `Array[(String, String)]` to `Map[String, String]`:

```
def getSchemaMap(schema: StructType): Map[String, String] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap {
    case StructField(name, StringType, _, _) => Map(name -> "String")
    case StructField(name, IntegerType, _, _) => Map(name -> "int")
    case StructField(name, LongType, _, _) => Map(name -> "int")
    case StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _) => Map(name -> "int")
    case StructField(name, TimestampType, _, _) => Map(name -> "timestamp")
    case StructField(name, DateType, _, _) => Map(name -> "date")
    case StructField(name, BooleanType, _, _) => Map(name -> "boolean")
    case StructField(name, _: DecimalType, _, _) => Map(name -> "decimal")
    case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Map(name -> "String")
  }.toMap
}
```

But actually you don't need to use `flatMap` here since you map one value to one value, not value to multiple values. So for that case you can just `map` values to tuples and then convert the List of tuples to Map

```
def getSchemaMap(schema: StructType): Map[String, String] = {
  schema.fields.map {
    case StructField(name, StringType, _, _) => name -> "String"
    case StructField(name, IntegerType, _, _) => name -> "int"
    case StructField(name, LongType, _, _) => name -> "int"
    case StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _) => name -> "int"
    case StructField(name, TimestampType, _, _) => name -> "timestamp"
    case StructField(name, DateType, _, _) => name -> "date"
    case StructField(name, BooleanType, _, _) => name -> "boolean"
    case StructField(name, _: DecimalType, _, _) => name -> "decimal"
    case StructField(name, _, _, _) => name -> "String"
 }.toMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except `flatmap` which will convert (`flatten`) `Array[Map(String, String)]` to `Array[(String, String)]`.

Replace `flatmap` with `map`.

```
def getSchemaMap(schema: StructType): Array[Map[String, String]] =
  schema.fields.map {
  //case statements
  }
```